# How can I prevent automap change?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Simple one. I create a gungame in my server and want to prevent the game changes maps at the end of a round. What was the command for this?

Comment: What would you like to have happen instead?

Comment: I want to play at same map over and over again. But it changes end of a game.

Comment: I believe you just need to edit your server's map cycle. Here's a tutorial for CS:S that may carry over: http://css.gamebanana.com/tuts/5326. Then just throw that file on your server with only the one map you want to play listed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `mp_match_end_restart "1"` makes restart at the end of every round.