# Counter Strike GO - How to start a custom map as deathmatch (practice with bots)?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, steam-workshop

When I install a custom map via SteamWorkshop, the SteamWorkshop map won't appear if I go offline (I don't like to connect to internet when I play game).

When I install a custom map manually by adding the map to the folder `.\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\maps`. I see that the map doesn't appear at all, the only way is start it with console cmd.

So how to start custom map as deathmatch (practice with bots)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by doing the following steps:

**Step 1:** Enable dev console for CS:GO
[image: CSGo Enable Dev Console.png]

**Step 2:** Open console with `~` key and execute this command to start the map:

```
game_mode 2;game_type 1;exec gamemode_deathmatch; mp_match_end_restart 1; map workshop\149093917\dm_rust;
```

[image: CSGo Open map image]

where `workshop\149093917\dm_rust` is my map, replace it with your map.

**Note:**
To come up with the command, I read the following sources:

[CSGO Game Mode Commands](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CSGO_Game_Mode_Commands).

[forcibly execute a deathmatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/326404/198960)

[How can I prevent automap change?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/106998)

I want to make a command menu (you know, commandmenu.txt, open by pressing H key) to save me from using console window. But I don't know how to setup command menu in CS:GO. Maybe I'll figure it out later. Currently I just save the command above to a text file and copy paste it to console window.

**Edit:**

I figure out how to automatically run the command when the game starts so it saves me from copying pasting the command above to console windows every time I play CS:GO.

Step 1: Create the file `autoexec.cfg` by doing the following:
Create a text file (with Notepad), paste the command above to the text file, save the text file as the name `autoexec.cfg`, then move this file to the folder `.\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg`
[image: CSGO autoexec.png]

Step 2: Set Launch Option for CS:GO by doing the following:
Open Steam, open Properties for CS:GO, in general tab, click `Set Launch Option...`, then paste this to the textbox: `-exec autoexec -novid`
[image: CSGO Startup cmd.png]

Note: I read the Launch Options at this page: [CSGO : Launch Options](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=379782151)